# Ocean scene - Why my rendered image is not similar to the viewport preview?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, 3d-view, ocean-simulation

I am trying to make an ocean scene but when I render it, it is not similar that preview in camera view mode and I do not know what to do in order to fix this.

Blender file link for your reference:
https://pasteall.org/media/a/3/a311d8909182a823b1bfafa3cba73f3b.blend

Does anybody know why my rendered image is not even similar to the preview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the *Ocean* modifier, you need to put the same value for *Render Resolution* and *Viewport Resolution*:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @moonboots that was really helpful